# Why can't I see the results of execvp() on the command line?

Tags: c, macos, process, operating-system, fork

Note that this is a homework assignment. The goal is to create a shell interface.

The question is why can't I see the results of execvp() on the terminal when I type in a command?

The code is as follows:

```
int getcmd(char *prompt, char *args[], int *background)
{
     int length, i = 0;
     char *token, *loc;
     char *line;
     size_t linecap = 0;

     printf("%s", prompt);
     length = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin);



     if (length <= 0) {
       exit(-1);
     }

    // Check if background is specified..
    if ((loc = index(line, '&')) != NULL) {
       *background = 1;
       *loc = ' ';
    } else
       *background = 0;

while ((token = strsep(&line, " \t\n")) != NULL) {
     for (int j = 0; j < strlen(token); j++)
        if (token[j] <= 32)
            token[j] = '\0';
        if (strlen(token) > 0)
          args[i++] = token;
      }

   return i;
}
```

The following is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    char *args[20];
    int bg;

    while(1){
        bg = 0;
        int cnt = getcmd("\n>>  ", args, &bg);
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        //for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        // printf("\nArg[%d] = %s", i, args[i]);

        // a negative number will be returned only 
        // if the forking was unsuccessful i.e
        // no child process is cloned from the original
        // process
        if(child_pid < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
            return 1;
         }

         // the return value for a successful fork of a child is 0
         else if(child_pid == 0){
             execvp(args[0], args);
         }

        // this is the parent process here
        else {
            int status;
            if (bg == 1){
                printf("\nBackground enabled..\n");
                getcmd("\n>>  ", args, &bg);
            }
            else{
                printf("\nBackground not enabled \n");
                waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
            }
        }
    }   
 }
```

When I run my code, it compiles and gives me the prompt(>>). When I run a command such as `ls`, it only prints Background not enabled(since I have not specified &). However, if I do a `ps` command on a different terminal, I see that there is a new process running. Am I overlooking something? Why can't I see the result of `ls` when I give it as an argument to the `execvp()` system call?

Comment: Does `getcmd()` `NULL`-terminate `args`?

Comment: Also the calls `perror("exec failed"); exit(1);` right after the call to `execvp()` could help.

Comment: Yes getcmd() null terminates and perror("exec failed") gives back: exec failed: Bad address

Comment: "*Bad address*"? When doing "ls"? Really? Which platform are you observing this on?

Comment: yes.. Mac OSX (More specifically: El Capitan)

Comment: So what do the macos man-pages tell you about this? "Bad Address" is `EFAULT`, btw.

Comment: My bet goes on a badly allocated or initialised `args`. Do `args`'s elements perhaps reference stack allocated memory valid locally to `getcmd()` only.

Comment: check with strace to see what's wrong

Comment: Yes, you want to show us the code for `getcmd()`, indeed.

Comment: Okay, please check the edited code now

Comment: Could you explain what the 32 here means. " if (token[j] <= 32)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getcmd()` misses to initialise `line`. It should initially point to `NULL`:

```
char *line = NULL;
```

From [getline()'s man-page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getline.3.html):

> If linep
>        points to a NULL pointer, a new buffer will be allocated.

---

Also please where do you `NULL`-terminate `args`. The element of `args` following the last one getting a value assigned by `getcmd()` should point to `NULL`.

You can make sure this is the case by initialising all of `args` elements to `NULL` in the very beginning by

```
char * args[20];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
  args[i] = NULL;
}
```

For testing one could initialise `args` like this

```
char * args[] = {
  "ls",
  "ls",
  "-alrt",
  NULL /* a must */
}
```

From [`execvp()`s man-page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html):

> The **execv()**, **execvp()**, and **execvP()** functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings
>        that represent the argument list available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention,
>        should point to the file name associated with the file being executed.  The array of pointers **must** be
>        terminated by a NULL pointer.

Comment: It is still giving the same error regardless of whether I initialize line or not

Comment: Perfect, it is working now. I still don't really get why you had to initialize them all to NULL first.

Comment: Not all, but only one past the last one. How else should `execve()` know which of `args`element points to valid memory. @Ralphyabro Setting all to `NULL` is just the lazy way. Btw, your app will not work for a command with more then 17 arguments.